# javascript in code behind syntax

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, jquery-ui

I am learning some code and there is script written in the backend (cs) of a site and I cannot find a tutorial that explains this syntax:

```
string scriptBlock = @"var aVar{0} = {1}
  $(document.ready(function){
         setTimeout('InitMiniChartAuto(\'{2}\',\'#placeholderSmallChart0{0}\',[{data:DataSmallChartAuto_0{0},lines: { show: false, fill: false},points: { show: false }}],{0})',{0}00);
});"
```

I just need someone to explain what is going on with the {0} and {1} in relation to the rest of the data. Or if someone knows of a tutorial that would be great. I can figure out what the rest of the jquery written if I new what the {} was doing.

Comment: That's for C#'s `string.Format()`.  It's probably an XSS hole.

Comment: If I had to guess, some other part of your C# backend is injecting values into those `{n}` placeholders

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This string is used probably in [string.Format()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.format%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

In `{}` placeholders you are putting values.

```
string result = String.Format(scriptBlock, variable1, variable2);
```

`variable1` will be replaced in the string `scriptBlock` where you have `{0}`.

If you have

```
string js = @"var a = {0}";
string result = String.Format(js,5);
// output: var a = 5;
```

You can check this things easily with debug.

Comment: Yea, or find where scriptBlock is used, that's probably where actual values are put in the placeholders.

Comment: Yes I am debugging. I was wondering mainly how the 'var x{0} ='  worked. I have never seen this before and I was thinking the 'var x =' would set it anyways? Why is there a placeholder in the initialization?